# count occurences in a specific way in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of double numbers between 1 and 10.

```r
a<-c(3.5, 1.2, 1, 5, 8, 6.9, 5.3, 1.2)
```

I have to have a dataframe of 10 classes(1 to 10), with the count of each classe, if the nimber does not occure, it must be presented with 1.

so the expected result is this one:

```r
> df
    a b
1   1 3
2   2 1
3   3 1
4   4 1
5   5 2
6   6 1
7   7 1
8   8 1
9   9 1
10 10 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using base R, convert `a` to integer and then `factor` with levels 1-10, count their occurrences using `table` and use `pmax` to replace 0 counts with 1.

```
stack(pmax(table(factor(as.integer(a), levels = 1:10)), 1))[2:1]

#   ind values
#1    1      3
#2    2      1
#3    3      1
#4    4      1
#5    5      2
#6    6      1
#7    7      1
#8    8      1
#9    9      1
#10  10      1
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, thats realy awsome

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R solution

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1)
df$b[as.numeric(names(z))] <- (z <- table(floor(a)))
```

such that

```
> df
    a b
1   1 3
2   2 1
3   3 1
4   4 1
5   5 2
6   6 1
7   7 1
8   8 1
9   9 1
10 10 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The base solution is probably better (I like it better), but here is a `dplyr` way.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(a = a) %>%
  count(a = factor(as.integer(a), levels = 1:10)) %>%
  complete(a, fill = list(n = 1))
```

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   a         n
   <fct> <dbl>
 1 1         3
 2 2         1
 3 3         1
 4 4         1
 5 5         2
 6 6         1
 7 7         1
 8 8         1
 9 9         1
10 10        1
```